# attach a constraint to a polygon body

Tags: matter.js

In `matter.js` I am constructing a random polygon body (actually a randomly shaped car with wheels). The set of vertices of this body are accessible using the `vertices` property. I want to select a random vertex and attach a constraint to it.

In my code `bodyB` is the car, and `bodyB` is a wheel.

```js
var axelB = Constraint.create({
    bodyB: body,
    bodyA: wheelB,
    pointB: { x: 0, y: 0 },
//    pointB: { x: -50, y: -20 },
    stiffness: 0,
    length: 0,
  });
```

Here `pointB` is an offset in reference to the centroid of the polygon.

All I want to do is select a random vertex and place the wheel on it but I do not know how to translate between the centroid's coordinates and a point on the vertex I've chosen.

[image]

In the attached image the wheel is drawn at the centroid, I want to put it on one of the body edges instead.

Comment: I think I found the solution. Matterjs has a centroid function which accepts the vertices of a body. If I select a random vertex and subtract the centroid from it then I end up with a position I can place the wheel on. It works good enough.

Comment: consider writing a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) with complete, runnable code to help future visitors.